# How do I change the RootViewController to another XIB?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I am trying to understand the fundamental concept of ViewControllers. For my purpose, I need to switch XIBs (not modally), but completely to save up memory. Basically I want to call another XIB and use its functions, then by pushing a button on that XIB, load up another XIB.

```
-(IBAction)GoToPage:(id)sender
{
    GoToPage *gotopage = [[[GoToPage alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:gotopage animated:YES];
}
```

I know that the above code just adds a subview modally. Could someone lead me in the right direction of how I would accomplish this?

This is for an iPad book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reading Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html) to gain a solid understanding of the purpose of view controllers.

As a quick overview, a view controller usually is responsible for managing a single "screenful" of content on phone-sized device, or a part of the screen on an iPad as multiple view controllers can be used on an iPad, e.g. `UISplitViewController`.  If you want to animate between fullscreen view controllers on an iPad, you could use a `UINavigationController`, which manges a hierarchy of view controllers. You don't mention what `GoToPage` inherits from, whether it's a `UIView` or `UIViewController`. In your case, it should be a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Using a `UINavigationController` would allow you to manage multiple `UIViewController` subclasses while keeping the hierarchy in-tact so the user can navigate back to the previous view controllers.  You would use `-pushViewController:animated:` to push a new instance of your view controller subclass onto the navigation controller's view controller stack and navigating back is handled automatically by the `UINavigationController` in most cases.

A XIB simply encapsulates the user-interface, not any user-defined code.  The XIB's file owner proxy should be set to your `UIViewController` subclass, which allows you to bridge the gap between the interface elements on the XIB and the code inside your `UIViewController` subclass through the use of `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` properties of your subclass.

Finally, if you are targetting iOS 5.0 only, I'd recommend looking into `UIPageViewController`, which manages multiple view controllers and allows you to transition between them with an iBooks-like page turning animation.  First and foremost though, read through the View Controller Programming Guide<sup>[1](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html)</sup>

Comment: Link is down - Please fix